# UIView memory address changing randomly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a custom `tableViewCell` which contains a custom `UIView`.  Within my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I alloc and init my custom `UIView` and check the address of the `UIView` object.  My custom `UIView` class also has a method called createArray that I call from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that gives me an array with `CGPoints` that I use to create a path.  I also check my UIView address at the end of my createArray method and it is consistent with what it was when I previously checked after I originally initialized the UIView.  The createArray method works fine and gives me a valid array.  However,after the method is done executing, `layoutSubviews` gets called immediately.  What I noticed when I reach `layoutSubviews` is that my `UIView` address is changing and the array I created to create my path goes to nil.  Anyone know whats happening?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString* identifier = @"audioTableCell";

    OSAudioTableCell *cell = [self.audioTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[OSAudioTableCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: identifier];
    }


    self.waveView = [[OSWaveView alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"self.view address %@", self.waveView);
    [self.waveView createArray:transferredAsset andSetSize:cell.waveView.bounds.size];

}

-(void) layoutSubviews
{

    if (!self.blueWave) {

        self.blueWave = [self createShapeLayer];

        self.blueWave.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

        self.redWave = [self createShapeLayer];
        self.redWave.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

        [self.layer addSublayer:self.blueWave];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:self.redWave above:self.blueWave];


        [self render];

    }

}
```

Is `layoutSubviews` reinitializing my view or is there some background method that gets executed that is causing everything to go to nil?  Also, I was thinking this might have to do with my UIView being an IBOutlet in storyboard and getting manually allocated/initialized.

Comment: Your question is unclear about what you're doing. In one place you say you're alloc init'ing the view in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but then you say it's an IBOutlet. Which is it? You should post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, if you're making the views there.

Comment: If it's a different address, it's a different object (and so things are not working the way you have been assuming they are).

Comment: You're adding new labels on top of old ones every time a cell is reused. If you're going to add subviews in cellFroRowAtIndexPath, then you need to check if a cell already has one before you add a new one.

Comment: @rdelmar the view is an IBOulet within my custom `tableViewCell`.  But how else would I be able to access the views createArray method  without alloc/init the View object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: When you say it's an IBOutlet, do you mean you created the label in IB, and connected an outlet to your cell?

Comment: @rdelmar Within my custom tableViewCell class I have `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet OSWaveView * waveView` Which I connect to my cell in interface builder.

Comment: Well, you don't want to alloc int a new view, that one won't ever appear in your cell. Just use cell.waveView to access the one you made in IB.

Comment: @rdelmar that was it!  Just had to change self to cell!  I don't know how I overlooked that.